# Openlayers 3 draw set name

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have following simple draw interaction:

```
draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    features: featureOverlay.getFeatures(),
    type: (type)
});
```

Now I would like to add attributes like a name and id to the feature. Is this possible? I couldn't find an awnser to this anywhere until now.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to add an event listener on the `draw` variable

```
draw.on('drawend', function(e) {
  e.feature.setProperties({
    'id': 1234,
    'name': 'yourCustomName'
  })
  console.log(e.feature, e.feature.getProperties());
});
```

Be aware that there is a a function `setId` on `e.feature` but this "id" is a bit different from the one you set in the attributes (see the [API docs](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.Feature.html#setId))