# OpenLayers problem with adding features to custom drawings

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, qgis2web

I would like to export the features drawn on my OpenLayers map in GeoJSON format.

So far everything is working apart from the `properties` section, which keeps coming with nothing, as you see below.

[image]

I would like to define something for every individual drawing I make on the map.

I found some nice approaches here:

[Openlayers 3 draw set name](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120698/openlayers-3-draw-set-name)

but it doesn't work in my code:

```
 var lineInteraction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
 type: 'LineString',
 source: vectorLayer.getSource()
 });
 lineInteraction.setActive(false);
 lineInteraction.on('drawend', onDrawend)  {
 feature.setProperties({
   'id':1234,
   'name': 'yourCustomName'
  });
  console.log(feature, feature.getProperties());
 });
```

Is it the OpenLayers library reason behind it? The aforementioned example refers to version 3.0.

My full JS fiddle is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/fb9mtyz3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting the properties inside the `drawend` handler

Either add a second listener

```
 lineInteraction.on('drawend', onDrawend);
 lineInteraction.on('drawend', function(e) {
   e.feature.setProperties({
     'id':1234,
     'name': 'yourCustomName'
    });
 });
```

Or call the default `onDrawend` function and set the properties inside a single handler

```
 lineInteraction.on('drawend', function(e) {
   onDrawend();
   e.feature.setProperties({
     'id':1234,
     'name': 'yourCustomName'
    });
 });
```