# OpenLayers Autoincrement ID for drawing features

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have the features drawn manually in OpenLayers. Since I have managed to set the properties for my drawings, i.e. by this thread:

[OpenLayers problem with adding features to custom drawings](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/412442/openlayers-problem-with-adding-features-to-custom-drawings)

I would like also to have the autoincrement ID.

I found a nice example here:

https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/NgIpC3

which pretty much shows how to do it, although the `GetID()` appears only once in this code.

My full code looks like this now:

```
 var lineInteraction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
 type: 'LineString',
 source: vectorLayer.getSource()
 });
 lineInteraction.setActive(false);
 lineInteraction.on('drawend', onDrawend);
 lineInteraction.on('drawend', function(e) {
 var title = prompt("Please provide the data", "untitled");
 var value = prompt("Please provide the value", "undefinied");
 e.feature.setProperties({
  'Id': GetID(),
  'Name': title,
  'Value': value,
   });
 });
```

I am getting an error from my console that:

**ReferenceError: GetID is not defined**

I just need to increment my ID.

As per the example:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026258/html-and-javascript-auto-increment-number

I tried to set the new variable and then assign it to my `'ID'`, although it throws ID 1 only

```
 var lineInteraction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
 type: 'LineString',
 source: vectorLayer.getSource()
 });
  lineInteraction.setActive(false);
  lineInteraction.on('drawend', onDrawend);
  lineInteraction.on('drawend', function(e) {
  var title = prompt("Please provide the data", "untitled");
  var value = prompt("Please provide the value", "undefinied");
  let x = 1
  var id = x++
  e.feature.setProperties({
  'Id': id,
  'Name': title,
  'Value': value,
   });
  });
```

How can I make an autoincrement the ID of my drawing feature in OpenLayers?

Comment: Have a look at `utility.js` module in the mentioned Plunker nice example.

Comment: As for what you have tried, put `let x = 1` as global var outside before `'drawend'` processing function.

Comment: I saw already the utility.js, but the function applies to the date only as I see.

Comment: Question was why do you get error `ReferenceError: GetID is not defined`. Simply because you didn't include function definition in your code.

Comment: Yes, I agree, thank you for showing me this function. I have forgotten to check other .js files. Will remember it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
   var idn ;
      function GetID(idn ){
    var tt = idn;
       tt++;
     return tt;
    }

 var lineInteraction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
 type: 'LineString',
 source: vectorLayer.getSource()
 });
 var idt=0;
 lineInteraction.setActive(false);
 lineInteraction.on('drawend', onDrawend);
 lineInteraction.on('drawend', function(e) {
 var title = prompt("Please provide the data", "untitled");
 var value = prompt("Please provide the value", "undefinied");
 e.feature.setProperties({
  'Id':  GetID(idt++),
  'Name': title,
  'Value': value,
   });
 });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).